# Listview selected item value - not Index

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem, listviewitem

I am working on a project (simple phone book) for personal use. [This is how it looks like](http://s24.postimg.org/4eprhylpx/screenshot_53.png):

I have a listview filled with contacts and everything was working perfectly untill I added this line of code, when everything became messed up.

```
listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

So, the problem is obvious. Let's say that there are 6 contacts in the list, and **Contact 1** lives in **City 1**, on **Address 1**, has a **Tel. No 1** [etc], and **Contact 2** lives in **City 2**, on **Address 2**, has a **Tel. No 2** etc. [...sequence continues...]

When I try to make some changes, for example, **Contact 5** suddenly gets the information of other contact, in this case, **Contact 7**. It doesn't matter whose information it gets though, the matter is that everything becomes messed up.

Also, if i want to delete all the contacts from the listview - it is not possible - there will always be one remaining. For example, if there were 6 of them, 5 would be deleted and there would be one left. Also, if there was 100 of them, it would delete 99 and the one would always remain as well.

I figured out that there is no sense to use index of selected item anymore and that I have to use value of the selected item now (instead of its index). But, the problem is I do not know how to do that.

Maybe it comes to listView1_SelectedIndexChanged only. Please note that i am just taking a guess, I am not completely sure.

If so, here is the code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
        textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Hometown;
        textBox3.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address;
        textBox4.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Phone;
        textBox5.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
        textBox6.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].AdditionalInfo;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday;
        textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox5.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox6.ReadOnly = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
        toolStripButton5.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I think the code is to big to upload it here, so [I uploaded the code here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/ftuew8):

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the right object to update you first need to find the object in the `People` collection that matches the object selected in the `ListView`.

```
Person i = People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == ((ListView) sender).SelectedItems[0].Text);
PopulateEditData(i); // refer below for method...
```

This can only work if you have the `MultiSelect` property set to false, otherwise you will need to get the right item from the collection of selected items.

As seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Once you have the right `Person` object, you will be able to retrieve and display the objects details in the text boxes:

```
private void PopulateEditData(Person selectedPerson)
{
    textBox1.Text = selectedPerson.Name;
    textBox2.Text = selectedPerson.Hometown;
    textBox3.Text = selectedPerson.Address;
    textBox4.Text = selectedPerson.Phone;
    textBox5.Text = selectedPerson.Email;
    textBox6.Text = selectedPerson.AdditionalInfo;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = selectedPerson.Birthday;
    textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox5.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox6.ReadOnly = true;
    dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
    toolStripButton5.Enabled = true;
}
```

I would also suggest setting the `selectPerson` as a property of your form or one of the classes available to it so it is a little easier to edit and save the data on the object.

For the removal part of the problem, use the `SelectedPerson` property for the item to be removed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            People.Remove(SelectedPerson);
            this.listView1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var person in People)
            {
                this.listView1.Items.Add(person.ToString());
                this.listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            this.listView1.Refresh();
            this.button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

Anyway, I have managed to solve the problem in the following way:

1) I have added:

```
private Person FindPerson(string name)
    {
        return people.Find(x => x.Name == name);
    }
```

2) I have replaced:

```
people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index]
```

with "person", where person is:

```
Person person = FindPerson(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
```

where FindPerson is:

```
private Person FindPerson(string name)
{
    return people.Find(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

Anyway, I keep getting error when I try to remove the last remaining contact. Even when I try to select it, not just remove it. Here you can take a look what error is about:

**IMAGE**: http://s24.postimg.org/ls4nak6et/Kruzeri.png

So, this is how it looks like now:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        Person person = FindPerson(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        textBox1.Text = person.Name;
        textBox2.Text = person.Hometown;
        textBox3.Text = person.Address;
        textBox4.Text = person.Phone;
        textBox5.Text = person.Email;
        textBox6.Text = person.AdditionalInfo;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = person.Birthday;
        textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox5.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox6.ReadOnly = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
        toolStripButton5.Enabled = true;
    }
```

and Save button:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Person person = FindPerson(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text); 
            person.Name = textBox1.Text;
            person.Hometown = textBox2.Text;
            person.Address = textBox3.Text;
            person.Phone = textBox4.Text;
            person.Email = textBox5.Text;
            person.Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            person.AdditionalInfo = textBox6.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox5.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox6.ReadOnly = true;
            dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected ", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        UserCount();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns null because no item is selected. So person is of course null. You should handle this in your FindPerson-Function.